# TeamCity: Changing database config for NUnit test runner

Tags: teamcity

Our TeamCity CI instance is unable to use the same database config as our dev machines when running tests against the database in the NUnit test runner.

What is the best approach to replacing the database connection strings in the config file?  I've looked through the TeamCity configuration menus and can't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that I'm aware of that is built into TeamCity that will allow you to do this however there are still a number of ways that you can achieve what you want. One is to create a Powershell script and execute it as part of the TeamCity build using the Powershell runner.

Your Powershell script might look something like this:

```
$config = 'C:\MyUnitTests.dll.config'
$doc = (Get-Content $config) -as [Xml]
$root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
$newCon = $root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.Replace('data source=SQL01','data source=SQL02');
$root.connectionStrings.add.connectionString = $newCon
$doc.Save($config)
```

Script borrowed from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sonam_rastogi_blogs/archive/2014/08/18/update-configuration-files-using-powershell.aspx